# Dockerfile is not running the desired shell script

Tags: docker, ros

I am trying configure and run a certain program using Docker. I am a beginner in Docker, so beware of newbie mistakes!

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

# create non-root user
ENV USERNAME ros
RUN adduser --ingroup sudo --disabled-password --gecos "" --shell /bin/bash --home /home/$USERNAME $USERNAME
RUN bash -c 'echo $USERNAME:ros | chpasswd'
ENV HOME /home/$USERNAME

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --assume-yes wget sudo && \
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/robotis_tools/master/install_ros_kinetic.sh && \
chmod 755 ./install_ros_kinetic.sh && \
bash ./install_ros_kinetic.sh
RUN  apt-get install --assume-yes ros-kinetic-joy ros-kinetic-teleop-twist-joy ros-kinetic-teleop-twist-keyboard ros-kinetic-laser-proc ros-kinetic-rgbd-launch ros-kinetic-depthimage-to-laserscan ros-kinetic-rosserial-arduino ros-kinetic-rosserial-python ros-kinetic-rosserial-server ros-kinetic-rosserial-client ros-kinetic-rosserial-msgs ros-kinetic-amcl ros-kinetic-map-server ros-kinetic-move-base ros-kinetic-urdf ros-kinetic-xacro ros-kinetic-compressed-image-transport ros-kinetic-rqt-image-view ros-kinetic-gmapping ros-kinetic-navigation ros-kinetic-interactive-markers

RUN cd /home/$USERNAME/catkin_ws/src/
RUN git clone https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3_msgs.git
RUN git clone https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3.git
USER $USERNAME
WORKDIR /home/$USERNAME

# add catkin env
RUN echo 'source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash' >> /home/$USERNAME/.bashrc
RUN echo 'source /home/$USERNAME/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash' >> /home/$USERNAME/.bashrc
RUN /bin/bash -c "source /home/ros/.bashrc && cd /home/$USERNAME/catkin_ws && catkin_make"
```

Gave the following output:

```
~/m/rosdocker docker build --rm -f "Dockerfile" -t rosdocker:latest .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  5.632kB
Step 1/15 : FROM ubuntu:16.04
 ---> b0ef3016420a
Step 2/15 : ENV USERNAME ros
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 25bf14574e2b
Step 3/15 : RUN adduser --ingroup sudo --disabled-password --gecos "" --shell /bin/bash --home /home/$USERNAME $USERNAME
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 3a2787196745
Step 4/15 : RUN bash -c 'echo $USERNAME:ros | chpasswd'
 ---> Using cache
 ---> fa4bc1d220a8
Step 5/15 : ENV HOME /home/$USERNAME
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f987768fa3b1
Step 6/15 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --assume-yes wget sudo && wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/robotis_tools/master/install_ros_kinetic.sh && chmod 755 ./install_ros_kinetic.sh && bash ./install_ros_kinetic.sh
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 9c26b8318f2e
Step 7/15 : RUN  apt-get install --assume-yes ros-kinetic-joy ros-kinetic-teleop-twist-joy ros-kinetic-teleop-twist-keyboard ros-kinetic-laser-proc ros-kinetic-rgbd-launch ros-kinetic-depthimage-to-laserscan ros-kinetic-rosserial-arduino ros-kinetic-rosserial-python ros-kinetic-rosserial-server ros-kinetic-rosserial-client ros-kinetic-rosserial-msgs ros-kinetic-amcl ros-kinetic-map-server ros-kinetic-move-base ros-kinetic-urdf ros-kinetic-xacro ros-kinetic-compressed-image-transport ros-kinetic-rqt-image-view ros-kinetic-gmapping ros-kinetic-navigation ros-kinetic-interactive-markers
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4b4c0abace7f
Step 8/15 : RUN cd /home/$USERNAME/catkin_ws/src/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> fb87caedbef8
Step 9/15 : RUN git clone https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3_msgs.git
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d2d7f198e018
Step 10/15 : RUN git clone https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3.git
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 42ddcbbc19e1
Step 11/15 : USER $USERNAME
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4526fd7b5d75
Step 12/15 : WORKDIR /home/$USERNAME
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 0543c327b994
Step 13/15 : RUN echo 'source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash' >> /home/$USERNAME/.bashrc
 ---> Using cache
 ---> dff40263114a
Step 14/15 : RUN echo 'source /home/$USERNAME/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash' >> /home/$USERNAME/.bashrc
 ---> Using cache
 ---> fff611e9d9db
Step 15/15 : RUN /bin/bash -c "source /home/ros/.bashrc && cd /home/$USERNAME/catkin_ws && catkin_make"
 ---> Running in 7f26a34419a3
/bin/bash: catkin_make: command not found
The command '/bin/sh -c /bin/bash -c "source /home/ros/.bashrc && cd /home/$USERNAME/catkin_ws && catkin_make"' returned a non-zero code: 127
~/m/rosdocker
```

I need it to run catkin_make (which is on the path set up by .bashrc)

Comment: `/bin/sh: 1: ./home/ros/.bashrc: not found` why is that relative?

Comment: @pitosalas: when editing a question, it is worth being wary about taking material from answers and applying those changes to make a new question. The reason for this is based on the purpose of Stack Overflow, which is to produce high-quality Q&A material. If a question is updated such that an answer is invalidated, then either the answer may be downvoted (which is not fair on the answer author) or your material may be rolled back. Knowing when a question is answered and when to create a new one is something of an art, but if you can ensure questions and answers match, that is a good start.

Comment: I see your point, but I've also had just the reverse advice from high rated SO users: Once you see that your question had an incorrect assumption, or was missing info, put that in the edit of the question, not in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Exit code 127 from shell commands means "command not found". Is `.bashrc` executable? Normally it is not, <strike>probably you want to source it?</strike>

```
source ./home/$USERNAME/.bashrc
```

As [Dan Farrel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1726083/dan-farrell) pointed out in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54271836/dockerfile-not-running-the-desired-shell-script/54271863?noredirect=1#comment95366603_54271863), sourcing the file in a `RUN` command will only have effect within that shell.

## To source .bashrc during the build

If you want it to have effect for later commands in the build you need to run them all in the same `RUN` statement. In the below `.bashrc`is sourced in the same shell as `catkin_make` is run.

```
RUN . /home/ros/.bashrc && \ 
    cd /home/$USERNAME/catkin_ws && \
    catkin_make
```

## To source the .bashrc file when the container starts

What should happen when the container is run using `docker run`is specified using the `ENTRYPOINT`statement. If you just want a plain bash prompt, specify `/bin/bash`. The   shell will be run with the user specified in the `USER` statement.

So in summary if you add the following to the end of your `Dockerfile`

```
USER ros
ENTRYPOINT /bin/bash
```

When someone runs the container using `docker run -it <containerName>` they will land in a bash shell as the user `ros`. Bash will automatically source the `/home/ros/.bashrc` file and all definitions inside will be available in the shell. (Your `RUN` statement containing the `.bashrc` file canbe removed

Comment: How do you source in a dockerfile? run source gives `/bin/sh: 1: source: not found

Comment: "not found" is typically distinct from "not executable" .

Comment: also, sourcing in a separate shell is not going to have any effect outside that shell, so even if the path did exist, this would not "do anything"

Comment: @pitosalas, Are you using bash? (Your output suggests /bin/sh, but could be a symlink of course). What Dockerfile are you inherting from?

Comment: @pitosalas >> what do you want to do with the .bashrc file? why is it important to "run" it?

Comment: Its part of the setup of the environment that I am trying to get to work. I am trying to convert an interactive shell procedure to get a robot environment configured into a docker container.

Comment: Ok, but as @DanFarrel points out, sourcing .bashrc will only have effect within that shell (within that RUN command), what you probably want to do is to source the .bashrc as part of starting your container up (extedning the entrypoint or cmd command), but that is hard to tell given the incomplete Dockefile in the OP.

Comment: thanks all... I posted the complete Dockerfile above

Comment: How will you use this container? There is not entrypoint or cmd defined ...

Comment: Ok my goal is this: setting up ROS is a pretty complicated procedure and many of my students struggle with it. So I am trying to see if I can turn it into a container that I can distribute to them or run in the cloud, that they run on their computers and do shell commands from within it. Is this a crazy idea?

Comment: Not at all, I assume that you then want .bashrc to be sourced when you start the container? I updated my answer with that.

Comment: @danielorn Thanks. What does the dot do in `RUN . /home/ros/.bashrc`

Comment: it is equivalent to source http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins